# Best way to group elements in an array with least complexity

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

I have a JSON array which looks like this:

```
var map_results = [{"Type":"Flat","Price":100.9},
                   {"Type":"Room","Price":23.5},
                   {"Type":"Flat","Price":67.5},
                   {"Type":"Flat","Price":100.9}
                   {"Type":"Plot","Price":89.8}]
```

This array contains about 100,000 records. I want the output to be grouped by "Type" and "Price". It should look like this:

```
var expected_output = [{"Type":"Flat", "Data":[{"Price":100.9, "Total":2},
                                               {"Price":67.5,  "Total":1}] },
                       {"Type":"Room","Data":[{"Price":23.5,"Total":1}]},
                       {"Type":"Plot","Data":[{"Price":89.8, "Total:1"}]}]
```

This has to be done in pure javascript and I cannot use libraries like undersore.js. I tried solving the problem but it had like 3 nested for loops which made the complexity as n^4. What could be a better solution for this problem??

The function I have looks like this:

```
var reduce = function (map_results) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i in map_results) {
      var type_found = 0;
      for(var result in results){
         if (map_results[i]["Type"] == results[result]["Type"]){
         type_found = 1;
         var price_found = 0;
         for(var data in results[result]["Data"]){
           if(map_results[i]["Price"] == results[result]["Data"][data]["Price"]){
              price_found = 1;
              results[result]["Data"][data]["Total"] +=1;
            }
          }
          if(price_found == 0){
            results[result]["Data"].push({"Price":map_results[i]["Price"], "Total":1});
          }
        }
      }
      if(type_found == 0){
        results.push({"Type":map_results[i]["Type"], "Data":[{"Price":map_results[i]["Price"],"Total":1}]});
   }
 }
 return results;
};
```

Comment: I think the better way is to show your 4-nested-for-loops, then we can help you optimise it

Comment: @Madedan Posted.. but oops 3 for loops..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried something like this:

```
 var reduce_func = function (previous, current) {

                        if(previous.length == 0){
                          previous.push({Type: current.Type, Data:[{Price:current.Price,Total:1}]});
                          return previous;
                        }
                        var type_found = 0;
                        for (var one in previous) {
                            if (current.Type == previous[one].Type){
                                type_found = 1;
                                var price_found = 0;
                                for(var data in previous[one].Data){
                                    if(current.Price == previous[one].Data[data].Price){
                                        price_found = 1;
                                        previous[one].Data[data].Total += 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(price_found == 0){
                                    previous[one].Data.push({Price:current.Price, Total:1});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(type_found == 0){
                            previous.push({Type:current.Type, Data:[{Price : current.Price ,Total:1}]});
                        }
                        return previous;
                      }

map_results.reduce(reduce_func,[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `Type`s and the `Price`s are unique after grouping I think a structure like `{"Flat": {"100.9":2,"67.5":1}, {"Room": {"23.5": 1}}}` would be easier to handle. So could do the grouping the following way:

```
var output = {};
map_results.map(function(el, i) {
  output[el["Type"]] = output[el["Type"]] || [];
  output[el["Type"]][el["Price"] = (output[el["Type"]][el["Price"]+1) || 1;
});
```

If you can not handle this structure you could do another mapping to your structure.
As you are iterating the Array one time this should have a complexity of n.

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XShHL/) for a working fiddle.

---

EDIT: So remap everything to your structure. The order of the remapping is far less then the first mapping, because the grouping is already done.

```
var expected_output = [];
for(type in output) {
  var prices = [];
  for(price in output[type]) {
    prices.push({"Price": price, "Total": output[type][price]);
  }
  expected_output.push({"Type": type, "Data": prices});
}
```

Comment: That is nice, but I don't think I can change the structure

Answer (score 0):

I have a short function that handles the first part of the requested functionality: It maps the `map_results` to the desired format:

```
var map_results = [{"Type":"Flat","Price":100.9},
                   {"Type":"Room","Price":23.5},
                   {"Type":"Flat","Price":67.5},
                   {"Type":"Flat","Price":100.9},
                   {"Type":"Plot","Price":89.8}]

var expected_output = map_results.reduce(function(obj, current){
    if(!obj[current.Type]){
        obj[current.Type] = {'Type':current.Type, 'Data':[]};
    }
    obj[current.Type].Data.push({'Price':current.Price, 'Total':1});
    return obj;
},{})
```

Then this piece of code is required to calculate the totals, I'm afraid:

```
for(var type in expected_output){
    var d = {};
    for(var item in expected_output[type].Data){
        d[expected_output[type].Data[item].Price] = (d[expected_output[type].Data[item].Price] || 0) + 1;
    }
    expected_output[type].Data = [];
    for(var i in d){
        expected_output[type].Data.push({
            'Price':i,
            'Total':d[i]
        })
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "Flat":{
        "Type":"Flat",
        "Data":[{"Price":"100.9","Total":2},
                {"Price":"67.5","Total":1}]
    },
    "Room":{
        "Type":"Room",
        "Data":[{"Price":"23.5","Total":1}]
    },
    "Plot":{
        "Type":"Plot",
        "Data":[{"Price":"89.8","Total":1}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is yet another effort. Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vjdwY/)

For performance testing, I also mocked up a [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/groupby) with 163840 elements. On Chrome(OSX) original solution is 90% slower than this one.

Few notes:

Feel free to optimize for your case (e.g. take out the hasOwnProperty check on object cloning).

Also, if you need the latest Total as the first element use `unshift` instead of push to add the obj the beginning of the array.

```
function groupBy(arr, key, key2) {
  var retArr = [];
  arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
   if(currentValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var kVal = currentValue[key];
       if(!previousValue.hasOwnProperty(kVal)) {
           previousValue[kVal] = {};
           retArr.push(previousValue[kVal]);
           previousValue[kVal][key] = kVal;
           previousValue[kVal]["Data"] = [];
       }
       var prevNode = previousValue[kVal];
       if(currentValue.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
           var obj = {};
           for(var k in currentValue) {
               if(currentValue.hasOwnProperty(k) && k!=key)
                   obj[k] = currentValue[k];
           }
           obj["Total"] = prevNode["Data"].length + 1;
           prevNode["Data"].push(obj);   
       }
    }
    return previousValue;
  }, {});
  return retArr;
}


var map_results = [{"Type":"Flat","Price":100.9},
               {"Type":"Room","Price":23.5},
               {"Type":"Flat","Price":67.5},
               {"Type":"Flat","Price":100.9},
               {"Type":"Plot","Price":89.8}];
var expected_output = groupBy(map_results, "Type", "Price");
console.dir(expected_output);
```